# Extrema of a multivariable function with trigonometric functions.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization, maxima-minima, karamata-inequality

I am trying to find and classify the extrema of the following function: $f(x,y,z)=\sin(x)+\sin(y)+\sin(z)-\sin(x+y+z)$, with $0\leq x \leq \pi, 0\leq y \leq \pi, 0\leq z \leq \pi$.

I have found three critical points: $(0,0,0),(\pi,\pi,\pi), (\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2})$. The hessian matrix only yields a conclusion for the point $(\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2})$, which is a maximum. But for the other points, the hessian matrix is null.

What I usually do in these cases is studying directly the increment of the funcion $f$ in such points. However, I do not manage to manipulate the expression of the increment in such a way that it is clear whether the point is a maximum, a minimum or a saddle point.

If anyone could give me a hint, it would be really helpful.

Thanks.

Comment: It might be easier to see by changing variables to $a=\frac{x+y}{2}$, $b=\frac{x+z}{2}$, $c=\frac{y+z}{2}$, or what is the same $x=a+b-c$, $y=a+c-b$, $z=b+c-a$, and writing $f(a,b,c)=4\sin(a)\sin(b)\sin(c)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\sum_{cyc}\sin{x}-\sin(x+y+z)\leq1+1+1+1=4.$$
The equality occurs for $x=y=z=\frac{\pi}{2},$ which says that we got a maximal value.

Also, 
$$\sin{x}+\sin{y}+\sin{z}-\sin(x+y+z)=$$
$$=\sin{x}+\sin{y}+\sin{z}-\sin{x}\cos(y+z)-\cos{x}\sin(y+z)=$$
$$=\sin{x}(1-\cos(y+z))+\sin{y}(1-\cos{x}\cos{z})+\sin{z}(1-\cos{x}\cos{y})\geq0.$$
The equality occurs for $x=y=z=0$ or for $x=y=z=\pi,$  which says that we got a minimal value.

We see that these critical points they are points of the global maximum or of the global minimum.

For finding of the minimal value also Karamata helps:

Let $x\geq y\geq z$.

Thus, since $\sin$ is a concave function on $[0,\pi]$ and $(x+y+z,0,0)\succ(x,y,z),$ we obtain:
$$\sin{x}+\sin{y}+\sin{z}\geq\sin(x+y+z)+\sin0+\sin0,$$ which gives
$$\sin{x}+\sin{y}+\sin{z}-\sin(x+y+z)\geq0.$$